# Conditioning data frames

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I am building a data frame to decide when to buy and sell stocks.

My first data frame looks something like this, where the observations are the percentual order of a given ratio at a given point in time.

```
AAPL <- c(0.25,0.25,0.25,0.5,0.5,0.75,0.5,1,1,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.25)
df <- data.frame (AAPL)
```

I want to write a condition where if the observation is below 0.4 I want to buy the stock (1) and if it is above 0.6 I want to sell (-1).

What I would like is to have something like this were I never buy a stock that I have not yet sold.

```
AAPL.new <- c(1,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)
df.new <- data.frame (AAPL.new)
```

So far, I have built the following function:

```
selection <- function(x) {
sapply(seq_along(x), function(i){
    if (i==1 & x[1]<0.4) {
        1
    } else if (is.na(x[i])) {
        0
    } else if (x[i] < 0.4 & is.na(x[i-1])) {
        1
    } else if (x[i] < 0.4 & x[i-1] > 0.4) {
        1
    } else if (x[i] > 0.6 & is.na(x[i-1])) {
        -1
    } else if (x[i] > 0.6 & x[i-1] < 0.6) {
        -1
    } else {
        0
    }        
})
}
```

However, the result this function yields is:

```
AAPL.new <- c(1,0,0,0,0,-1,0,-1,0,0,0,0,1)
```

which is wrong since I am selling twice the stock without buying it (represented in the two "-1" in observations 6 and 8).

I am a begginer moving from small samples in Excel to larger samples in R.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You may want to add some more code showing what you are trying to do. It is not clear (to me anyway) what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Kevin I have updated the post with the code I have and where it isn't working. Do you understand now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according what i understand!!!:
. first aapl and boolean canibuy as Global variables. canibuy is a varibale tha help you to understand that u are in buying or selling level.

```
aapl<<-c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.75, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.25)
canibuy<<-T

 iequal1<-function(xi){
 retvalue<-0

                            if(is.na(xi)) {retvalue<-0
                                        } else if(xi<.4){
                                            retvalue<-1;canibuy<<-F     
                                                    }else  {
                                                  retvalue<-0;canibuy<<-T

                                                       }
return(retvalue)
 }
 ####check with values
  iequal1(0);canibuy
 iequal1(.5);canibuy
  iequal1(.6);canibuy

  inotequal1<-function(i){
  retvalue<-0
  if(canibuy){
    if(is.na(aapl[i])) { retvalue<-0
                       }else if(aapl[i]<.4){
                                               retvalue<-1;canibuy<<-F
                                              }else{
                                                      retvalue<-0
                                                    }
   }else  {
             if(is.na(aapl[i])) { retvalue<-0
                           }else if(aapl[i]>.6){
                                      retvalue<--1;canibuy<<-T
                                                   }else{
                                                        retvalue<-0
                                                        }

            }
return(retvalue)
}

selection<-function(){
sapply(seq_along(aapl),function(i){
                   retvalue<-0

                    if(i==1){##i==1
                             retvalue<-iequal1(aapl[i])
                            }else{ 
                                              retvalue<-inotequal1(i)
                                    }
                        return(retvalue)
                            }


 )
 }

selection()
##[1]  1  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! It was exactly this